# VERTEX AI, BATCH PREDICTION

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Does anyone know how I can choose the option "Files on Cloud Storage (file list) in the program? How can I [enter image description here choose the list format?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can't enter multiple files in the UI. You point it to one text file in cloud storage, and that file should contain the paths of all the images you want to run predictions on. Here is [the file format](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/get-predictions#input_data_requirements).